# RoR - Blog entries with 'View More' expand and collapse only points to first article

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to solve out an basic issue regarding the overview for a blog page.

I want to display blog entries on the overview page but only want to show a short snippet of the entry - then the user can expand the article with a 'View More' button.

At the moment it only targets one article and does work on the other article.

Here is the code

```
    <% @articles.each do |article|%>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= image_tag article.banner.url (:banner)%>
        <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
        <p><%= article.introduction %></p>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="article-item" />
            <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target"><%= article.body %></span></p>
            <label for="article-item" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <%end%>
    </div>
```

But the id="article item' only works once and on the latest entry.
How can I get it to work on all blog entries ??

The CSS is fine for now and not worried about the styling..

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'View More';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'View Less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #55c7eb;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Only looking to get the functionality across blog entries.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each HTML `id` should be unique within a page. If something is triggered on a page, via it's `id` the browser will only look for the first one - because there shouldn't be another one. In your example - only the first article is affected at it is the first with the `id` `article-item`.

So if you have a number of items that are detected via their `id` you will need to give each one its own unique (within the page) `id`. The easiest way to do that is to increment it. In your example, I presume each article has an `id` so use that:

```
<% article_id = "article-#{article.id}" %>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="<%= article_id %>" />
  <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target"><%= article.body %></span></p>
  <label for="<%= article_id %>" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
```